# verlet/leapfrog method lorentz force application

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, algorithms

So I ll use leapfrog/varlet algorithm to calculate the trajectory of the particle
In leapfrog method  for initial values we need $v_{-1/2}$ and  $x_0$. Hence I can write
$v_{-1/2}=v_0-Δt/2a_0$
 $v_0$ is given as $0$ , but $a_0$  should be also given to us right ?

and  $x_0$ also given as $0$

In the Verlet/leapfrog method for damped systems we can write the system equation as
$a(x,v,t)=1/m[F(x,t)-G(v)]$

Since I am doing lorentz force it will look like
$\vec{a}(x,v,t)=q/m[\vec{E}(x,t)-\vec{G}(v)]$ where $G(v)=\vec{v}×\vec{B}$
or in component-wise
$a_x(x,v,t)=q/m[E_x(x,t)-G_x(v)]$
$a_y(x,v,t)=q/m[E_y(x,t)-G_y(v)]$
$a_z(x,v,t)=q/m[E_z(x,t)-G_z(v)]$

so for example
let us think one component x

it says that we should approximate the $a_x(x,v,t)$ to $q/m[E_x(x,t)-G_x(v_{n-1/2})]$ then we have
$v_{n+1/2}=v_{n-1/2}+Δt[E_x(x,t)-G_x(v_{n-1/2})]$

In here we should set $v_{n-1/2}=v_{-1/2}=v_0-Δt/2a_0$ I guess but I am not sure what should I do with $G_x(v_{n-1/2})$

this is the first problem

Next since I know the $v_{n+1/2}$, I can use it in the

$x_{n+1}=x_n+Δt[v_{n+1/2}]$  equation. Now I can solve the problem I guess ?

In the code process I should set a $dt=0.0001$ or something like that and multiply it by $n$ for in loop right ?